# Adjusting layer order in Lizmap

Tags: qgis, openlayers, lizmap

I'm trying to add a WMS layer in [Lizmap](https://docs.lizmap.com/current/es/publish/customization/javascript.html), but I want the points on the map to appear on top. Currently, when I add WMS layers, they cover the points from other layers on the map. I use this code to add layers and it's adding layers but on top

```
var onLayerCreated = () => {
$('.menu-content select').append($('<option>', { value: getSelectedLayers('wms-layers') }).text(layerName))
if ($('.menu-content select option').length === 1) {
    createEvent('OL_CHANGE_VISIBLE_LAYER', { layerName: layerName })
    $('.menu-content select').find(`option[text="${layerName}"]`).attr('selected', 'selected')
    $('.menu-content select').change()
}

$('#switcher-baselayer').css('display', 'block')
}

var serviceType = $('#addBaseLayer .service-type input:checked').val();
var data = {
  service: serviceType,
  url: getProxyServiceURL(),
  layers: getSelectedLayers('wms-layers'),
  projection: 'EPSG:2180',
  layerName: getInputValue('wms-name'),
  callback: onLayerCreated
  }     
createEvent('OL_ADD_NEW_LAYER', data);
```

[layers with points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoZ87.jpg), [wms layer covering other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClpG6.jpg)

I tried changing the order and visibility in `Lizmap.layers`, but it didn't work. I'm using lizmap 3.7

Comment: How do you add a WMS Layer? Which Lizmap version do you have?